# What is the proper way to read-write list of words?

Tags: flutter, flutter-linux

I created a mixture of two example codes, one from https://dartpad.dev/?id=e7076b40fb17a0fa899f9f7a154a02e8 and one from https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files. I want to save in file the words what was liked by the user. For this I've created a new menu option.

This is my code:

```
`// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Namer App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.blueGrey),
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Storage {
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/counter.txt');
  }

  Future<List> readWordList() async {
    try {
      final file = await _localFile;

      // Read the file
      // final contents = await file.readAsString();

      //
      List<String> lines = await file.readAsLines();
      //
      /*for (String line in lines) {
        print(line);
      }*/
      return lines;

    } catch (e) {
      // If encountering an error, return 0
      List<String> lines = [];
      lines[0] ="ERR: Empty file!";
      return lines;
    }
  }

  Future<File> writeWord(String word) async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$word\n');
  }
}

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var current = WordPair.random();
  var history = <WordPair>[];

  GlobalKey? historyListKey;

  void getNext() {
    history.insert(0, current);
    var animatedList = historyListKey?.currentState as AnimatedListState?;
    animatedList?.insertItem(0);
    current = WordPair.random();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  var favorites = <WordPair>[];

  void toggleFavorite([WordPair? pair]) {
    pair = pair ?? current;
    if (favorites.contains(pair)) {
      favorites.remove(pair);
    } else {
      favorites.add(pair);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeFavorite(WordPair pair) {
    favorites.remove(pair);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var colorScheme = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;

    Widget page;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = GeneratorPage();
        break;
      case 1:
        page = FavoritesPage();
        break;
      case 2:
        page = SavingPage();
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError('no widget for $selectedIndex');
    }

    // The container for the current page, with its background color
    // and subtle switching animation.
    var mainArea = ColoredBox(
      color: colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
      child: AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        child: page,
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (constraints.maxWidth < 450) {
            // Use a more mobile-friendly layout with BottomNavigationBar
            // on narrow screens.
            return Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: mainArea),
                SafeArea(
                  child: BottomNavigationBar(
                    items: [
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                        label: 'Home',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                        label: 'Favorites',
                      ),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                        label: 'Save',
                      ),
                    ],
                    currentIndex: selectedIndex,
                    onTap: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Row(
              children: [
                SafeArea(
                  child: NavigationRail(
                    extended: constraints.maxWidth >= 600,
                    destinations: [
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                        label: Text('Home'),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                        label: Text('Favorites'),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                        label: Text('Save'),
                      ),
                    ],
                    selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                    onDestinationSelected: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedIndex = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(child: mainArea),
              ],
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GeneratorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var pair = appState.current;

    IconData icon;
    if (appState.favorites.contains(pair)) {
      icon = Icons.favorite;
    } else {
      icon = Icons.favorite_border;
    }

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: HistoryListView(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          BigCard(pair: pair),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  appState.toggleFavorite();
                },
                icon: Icon(icon),
                label: Text('Like'),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  appState.getNext();
                },
                child: Text('Next'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Spacer(flex: 2),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BigCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const BigCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.pair,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final WordPair pair;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = Theme.of(context);
    var style = theme.textTheme.displayMedium!.copyWith(
      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
    );

    return Card(
      color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: AnimatedSize(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          // Make sure that the compound word wraps correctly when the window
          // is too narrow.
          child: MergeSemantics(
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                Text(
                  pair.first,
                  style: style.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                ),
                Text(
                  pair.second,
                  style: style.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FavoritesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = Theme.of(context);
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    if (appState.favorites.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No favorites yet.'),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: Text('You have '
              '${appState.favorites.length} favorites:'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          // Make better use of wide windows with a grid.
          child: GridView(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
              maxCrossAxisExtent: 400,
              childAspectRatio: 400 / 80,
            ),
            children: [
              for (var pair in appState.favorites)
                ListTile(
                  leading: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete_outline, semanticLabel: 'Delete'),
                    color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
                    onPressed: () {
                      appState.removeFavorite(pair);
                    },
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    pair.asLowerCase,
                    semanticsLabel: pair.asPascalCase,
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SavingPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = Theme.of(context);
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    final storageHandler = context.watch<Storage>();

    if (appState.favorites.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No favorites yet.'),
      );
    } else{
      for(var word in appState.favorites){
        storageHandler.writeWord(word.asPascalCase);
      }

      return Center(
        child: Text('Favorites saved!'),
      );
    }
  }
}

class HistoryListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HistoryListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HistoryListView> createState() => _HistoryListViewState();
}

class _HistoryListViewState extends State<HistoryListView> {
  /// Needed so that [MyAppState] can tell [AnimatedList] below to animate
  /// new items.
  final _key = GlobalKey();

  /// Used to "fade out" the history items at the top, to suggest continuation.
  static const Gradient _maskingGradient = LinearGradient(
    // This gradient goes from fully transparent to fully opaque black...
    colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black],
    // ... from the top (transparent) to half (0.5) of the way to the bottom.
    stops: [0.0, 0.5],
    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    appState.historyListKey = _key;

    return ShaderMask(
      shaderCallback: (bounds) => _maskingGradient.createShader(bounds),
      // This blend mode takes the opacity of the shader (i.e. our gradient)
      // and applies it to the destination (i.e. our animated list).
      blendMode: BlendMode.dstIn,
      child: AnimatedList(
        key: _key,
        reverse: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        initialItemCount: appState.history.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          final pair = appState.history[index];
          return SizeTransition(
            sizeFactor: animation,
            child: Center(
              child: TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  appState.toggleFavorite(pair);
                },
                icon: appState.favorites.contains(pair)
                    ? Icon(Icons.favorite, size: 12)
                    : SizedBox(),
                label: Text(
                  pair.asLowerCase,
                  semanticsLabel: pair.asPascalCase,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

This is the Error what I got when I click to the save option:

````
`======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building SavingPage(dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<MyAppState?>, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#c825f]]):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Storage> above this SavingPage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that SavingPage is under your MultiProvider/Provider<Storage>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter`
````

I'm newbie in Flutter, please give me some ideas how can I do this very simple thing?